# display images in tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

i have to  display images in tableview cell on clicking forward button on image but after scrolling tableview images are changing...
I have given tag value to each button in cell and stored  all cell references in array and on clicking forward button i am identifying reference in array and changing  image for that particular reference..

[image]

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  //  static NSString *cellidentifier = @"cell";
   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[LotsandLandTableCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
   // cell.smallimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[_smallimagesarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //if ( [str_scroll isEqualToString: @"scrolling"]) {

  //  }else{
    cell.bigimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[_bigimagesarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //}

     cell.forwardbutton.tag =indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@" %p",cell);
    [cell.forwardbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonInfo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 CellModel *cellmodel=[[CellModel alloc]init];
    cellmodel.tagValue=cell.forwardbutton.tag;
    cellmodel.cellobj=cell;
    [arrofcells addObject:cellmodel];
    NSLog(@"%p",cell);
    return cell;

}


-(void)buttonInfo:(UIButton *)sender{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSInteger tag = btn.tag;

   CellModel *cmodel=[[CellModel alloc]init];

    cmodel=[arrofcells objectAtIndex:tag];
    democell=(LotsandLandTableCell *)cmodel.cellobj;


   previoustag=cmodel.tagValue;
 if(cmodel.tagValue==previoustag)
   {

       if(j<_bigimagesarr1.count){
       democell.bigimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[_bigimagesarr1 objectAtIndex:j]];
      NSLog(@"j value is  is  %d",j);
           j++;

      }else{
          j=0;
         [democell.forwardbutton setEnabled:NO];

       }

  }
}
```

cellModel contains the cell references and property tag

```
@interface CellModel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger tagValue;
@property(nonatomic,strong) id cellobj;
@end
```

Comment: Don't use tags.  Why not simply supply the array of images to your cell and handle the buttons within the cell class?  Also, you are adding your button handler every time when cells are reused.

Comment: @Paulw11 didnt get you,can u be more speciific

Comment: You are trying to handle the button taps in your table view controller, which means that you need to identify which cell the button tap happened in, for which you are using the tag.  Tags are fragile since cells are reused and can be reordered.  If you simply set the array of images as a property on your custom cell class then each cell can handle its own button taps and just move through its array of images.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code doesn't use an appropriate separation of concerns; your table view controller doesn't care about which image is currently displayed in the cell, so trying to process the button taps in the table view controller is unnecessarily complicated.

You haven't shown all of your source code, so what I have may not match your code 100% - I am making educated guesses.  Also you seem to have two different arrays of images, which I presume is just your testing approach.  In reality you should have a single array of images per cell, with each array contained in some other data structure, an array of which is your data source for your tableview.

**LotsandLandTableCell.h**

-(void)setImages:(NSArray *)images;

**LotsandLandTableCell.m**

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) NSArray *bigImages;
 @property NSInteger imageIndex;

-(void) prepareForReuse {
    self.bigImages = nil;
    self.bigimage.image = nil;
    self.imageIndex = 0;
}

-(void) setImages:(NSArray *)images {
    if (images != null) {
        self.bigImages = images;
        self.imageIndex = 0;
        [self updateBigImage];
    }
}

@IBAction forwardTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (self.images.count == 0) {
        return;
    }
    self.imageIndex = (self.imageIndex + 1) % self.images.count;
    [self updateBigImage];
}

@IBAction backwardTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
   if (self.images.count == 0) {
       return;
   }
   self.imageIndex -= 1;
   if (self.imageIndex < 0) {
       self.imageIndex = self.bigImages.count;
   }
   [self updateBigImage];
}

- (void) updateBigImage {
    self.bigimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.images[self.imageIndex]];
}
```

**View Controller**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    LotsandLandTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[LotsandLandTableCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

     NSArray *yourImagesArray = yourDataArray[indexPath.row].bigImages; // Change this

     [cell setImages:yourImageArray];

     return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in LotsandLandTableCell class

```
-(void)prepareForReuse {
    _bigimage.image = nil;
 }
```

When you scroll tableView images are changing because it may use the previous image so when the tableView reuse its cell, its better to clear the previous cell data.

Comment: still images are changing

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with the way you are displaying rows and images.

You need to follow below steps for best results:

1. Create a item Model for populating data in row(In your case  CellModel can also work)
   Following could be property of the Model:

   - ItemID
   - Price
   - Description
   - area
   - imageNames(Array), etc

imageNames array will contains all the image names you want to display on forward click on particular row.

Assign this item object to your LotsandLandTableCell class, and handle forward button callback in cell itself, on forward click pick another name from the imagenNames array and set it to imageView.

So by using above approach you can implement this whiteout having any problem.

You can create array of all your properties(one Item Model will represent one property).

Below sample can be taken as reference:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return items.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  //  static NSString *cellidentifier = @"cell";
   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[LotsandLandTableCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

cell.item = [items objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    return cell;

}
```

Now in your custom cell class you can implement the rest logic to populate your all cell data: